# LocationCollection not tagged as ScriptableType but can be instantiated in script (How come?)

Tags: javascript, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, virtual-earth, htmlbridge

I'm working on a small silverlight application that involves passing some data between javascript and silverlight.  I am also using the silverlight virtual earth control.

The weirdness I have come across is that is possible to register Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.LocationCollection as a script createable type and instantiate and pass it to a ScriptableMember.  This is great, but I can't see where LocationCollection is tagged as a ScriptableType - am I missing something obvious.

Code in App.xaml.cs - Application_Startup

```
HtmlPage.RegisterCreateableType("mapLocationCollection", typeof(Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.LocationCollection));
```

Javascript code that works!

```
var locs = SLPlugin.Content.services.createObject('mapLocationCollection');
```

I thought that in order in instantiate an instance of the class in JavaScript the type needed to be tagged as [ScriptableType] and the type needs to be registered as a createable type.  As far as I can tell LocationCollection (or any of it's superclasses) have this attribute.

Can anyone out there help me square this in my mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the `ScriptableType` attribute specifies that all public properties, methods and events on the type are scriptable.   This simply saves having mark them all with `ScriptableMember`.

Comment: Is that right?  The material I have says that the RegisterScriptableObject method (System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage) associates an instance of a scriptable object (its class is decorated with ScriptableType) with a string alias.  Page 324 of Accelerated Silverlight 3 - apress.com.

Comment: Read the remarks section of the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptabletypeattribute(VS.95).aspx